# .Net Office Word Setup

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

In my Application I do office word's development and I referenced Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll but It build failed, through I can't see the error information in errorslist, is anyone can tell me why,and how can I resolve this problem

Comment: you don't provide any information needed to give you an answer... does it fail while building the project ? does it fail at runtime ? what sort of project is this (i.e. ASP.NET / WinForms / WPF...) ? Which Office version (i.e. 200 / 2003 / 2007 / 2010...) ? Is Office installed on the dev and/or runtime machine ? please show some source code...

Comment: my application is wpf, my office version 2007

Comment: what about my other questions ?

Comment: It failed during building the project and the target machine installed the office 2007

Comment: IF it failed during build there must be some sort of message in VS... also show some source code please!

Comment: There is no error message show in error list, but a message show building failed at the vs bottom

Comment: sorry but there is no way to help you without either some source code and/or an error message!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are referencing to the wrong version of Interop.word from GAC add the current version that should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio should always give you the error when a build fails.  Try cleaning the solution and rebuild all and see if that makes a difference.  If not, try removing the Office assembly reference and then rebuild (check if there are any errors) and then add the reference again.